# jquery script prevent another script from working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

My wordpress blog is making use of the newsticker aink scrolling plugin and i'm now implementing a jquery vertical scrolling demo.

The jQuery vertical scrolling demo requires the following

```
<script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script><script type="text/javascript">google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");</script>
```

When the above code is put in, the vertical scroll works, but the newsticker doesn't work and vice versa.

Any help on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one idea I can think of is that the newsticker plugin also uses jquery. You can verify that's the case by taking out your jquery include and seeing if the vertical scroll demo still works.

Comment: I checked on this possibility. It uses only the following two jscripts.
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="'.$NewsTickerAink_path.'/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>';
 echo '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="'.$NewsTickerAink_path.'/js/easing.js"></script>';

Comment: @sledge81 Can you post the source to those js files in pastebin.com or some other paste service and provide a link?

Comment: will do so. I'm trying to check on something which I think I might have missed. Will post back shortly

Comment: @sledge81 In these cases I normally use Firebug addon for Firefox, or Chrome's developer console to check for JS errors. Actually being able to fix it is another story.

Comment: Yep i'm using firebug :) It throws up a bunch of other jquery errors.. strangely unrelated to this issue!!

Comment: Ok, so here's the pastebin for newsticker.php the main file that manages the jquery scripts. http://pastebin.com/b7BcFuDJ

An interesting point to note is that.. I created a local html file copying the site's source code. In my local file when I remove the google.load for jquery the vertical scroll continues to work just fine. However this is not the case when I update the same on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly jQuery gets in conflict with other JavaScripts. You can use

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

and replace all `$()` with `jQuery()`

Comment: Alp... despite all instances of $() being replaced with jQuery, this error still throws up

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of calling google.load you can check

```
if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined")
   google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
```

Of course you could still have issues if their version isn't high enough to support what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I replaced the google.load with the following:
'<script type="text/javascript">
 if (typeof(jQuery) == "undefined")
   google.load("jquery", "1.4.4");
   }'

The vertical scroll continues to work but the newsticker isn't

Comment: Since jquery appears to be available (this script is basicly doing nothing) it would appear your first script is breaking the news ticker.  Its not needed since jquery is available.   Try removing it.